While trying to run docker app from docker compose file I am getting the error : 00342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
below is my dockerfile
---
version: "3"

services:
  myapp:
    image: 872515278889.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/gradebookapp:0.0
    ports: 
    - "9090:8080"

  mysqlserver:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports: 
    - "3307:3306"
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ashish
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
volumes:
     - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
    
volumes:
  my-datavolume:

and these are my application properties
spring.application.name= GradeBook Project

## Server Properties
server.port= 8080
##jdbcsql settings
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =create


spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ashish
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


Please ignore the commented text
I solved the initial problem , mysql container takes time to start and therefore was not available for connection to the spring app... but if I try to use local volume to persist data I am again getting the error.
Please someone guide me
